# A/C Compressor Clutch Not Engaging

Tags: honda, ac, civic, air-compressor

I have a 2007 Honda Civic Si. During the summer, the AC started acting up. It would work well for a couple minutes and then stop working. I remember checking to see if the compressor was running and it wasn't. I was going to replace the compressor clutch to see if that would fix it.

I ended up being busy in the summer and didn't change it. I went back to check again if that was the issue, but now the AC works fine again in the beginning, then blows fresh air, but not cold. I ran it for 30 minutes and the compressor was still spinning so the clutch was engaging.

It is winter right now for me. **Is there any reason to expect the compressor clutch to engage better during the winter as opposed to the summer?** Now that the clutch is engaging, but air is still not cold I am beginning to doubt that it is indeed a result of the clutch not engaging.

Comment: It may not be a good idea to just change the clutch\compressor Willy nilly. Your symptoms mirror closer to pressure problems. It would probably save you lots of money if you had this properly diagnosed. It is very possible that properly adjusting refrigerant could be all that is needed.

Comment: I've checked the refrigerant and it was at the proper levels. I took it in to get diagnosed and I don't remember what they told me was wrong with it, but I do remember they said they had to replace the whole AC system.

Comment: There'll be a pressure switch on one of the lines somewhere in the engine bay that cuts out the compressor if the coolant levels are low. Would be worth checking whether the connections to that are good - and for that matter the inline connector to the compressor clutch, and whether the switch is opening during operation causing the clutch to drop out.

Comment: Some cases the air gap on the AC clutch is too wide for proper engagement due to wear of the surfaces, causing all sorts of symptoms, most compressors have clutch shims that can be removed to close the gap a bit.